# How to change the color/size/etc of dynamically created buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have created dynamic buttons in vuejs where each button represents a different answer to a question. 
My goal is: when I get the answer wrong, the correct option is highlighted in green until the next question is shown. 
Is it also possible to change other settings of these "BaseButtons" with CSS? How can I do this?

```
<template>
  <div class="container-botoes">
     <BaseButton class="optionsButtons" 
     v-for="options in optionsAnswers" 
     :key="options.id" @click="handleAnswer(options)">
       {{options.ans}}
     </BaseButton>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
methods:{
  handleAnswer(options){
    if (options.id === this.correctAnswer){
      this.playerHit = true;
    }
    else {
      this.opponentHit = true;
      
    }
    this.nextquestion();
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create css classes with styles you need and append them to BaseButton component depending on your conditions

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one:

**HTML block:**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-botoes">
    <BaseButton
      v-for="(options, index) in optionsAnswers"
      :key="options.id"
      class="optionsButtons"
      :class="correctAnsIndex === index ? 'green-button' : 'red-button'"
      @click="handleAnswer(options, index)"
    >
      {{ options.ans }}
    </BaseButton>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**JavaScript block:**

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      correctAnsIndex: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAnswer(options, index) {
      if (options.id === this.correctAnswer) {
        this.playerHit = true
        this.correctAnsIndex = index
      } else {
        this.opponentHit = true
        this.correctAnsIndex = null
      }
      this.nextquestion()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

**CSS block:**

```css
<style>
.red-button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.green-button {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
```

**Code explanation:**

We have passed the `index` of the loop in the `handleAnswer` method, where the value of the `index` will be assigned to the `correctAnsIndex` variable if `options.id === this.correctAnswer` and in the else part we will assign `null` value to the `correctAnsIndex` variable.

Now, we have applied conditional classes in HTML block, where if the `index` and `correctAnsIndex` matches then it would apply `green-button` class or else it will apple `red-button` class.

Eventually getting your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **:**

```js
Vue.component('basebutton', {
  data() {
    return {
        isCorrect: false
    }
  },
  props: ['answerobj'],
  template: `<button :class="{ 'green': isCorrect, 'white': !isCorrect}" @click="handleAnswer(answerobj)">{{ answerobj.answer }}</button>`,
  methods: {
    handleAnswer(answerobj) {
      if (answerobj.correct) {
            this.isCorrect = true
      } else {
        this.isCorrect = false
      }
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{
      question: 'Who is the tallest animal ?',
      optionsAnswers: [{
        answer: 'Elephant',
        correct: false
      }, {
        answer: 'Jirafe',
        correct: true
      }, {
        answer: 'Lion',
        correct: false
      }, {
        answer: 'Zebra',
        correct: false
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
  <p><strong>Question : </strong>{{ item.question }}</p>
  <p><strong>Answers :</strong></p>
  <BaseButton v-for="(options, i) in item.optionsAnswers" :key="i" :answerobj="options">
  </BaseButton>
  </div>
</div>
```